# Duplicator Pro plugin with Docker on local?

Tags: migration, docker, sandbox

I have the [Duplicator Pro plugin](https://snapcreek.com/). In the past it was fairly easy to use. I have a wordpress site on a server, I'm trying to bring it down/migrate it down into a local sandbox. I have my local wordpress instance setup with Docker. Spinning it up initially with Docker was very easy and was tired of the clunky MAMP/WAMP tools. However migrating the site down while using Docker locally has been a challenge. With the Duplicator pro plugin the `/installer.php` script isn't read at all.

[image]

Comment: In the screen shot, it shows going to install.php and not install**er**.php. Did you try **installer.php** and it, too, doesn't work?

Comment: Neither work, sorry, wrong screenshot. Both display that.